# Automatically add an excel file as one part of a list item in SharePoint

Tags: list, excel

In order to streamline my company's request process, I am setting up a few lists on SharePoint.

Essentially what I am trying to do is set up this list so that whenever an employee adds an item, a blank copy of the expense report pops up (it's an excel file).

How do I set this up? since it would require numerous lines I can't just make one line hold all of the information.

This is the file I want to pop up every time, and whenever they fill this out it'll be added to the list as its own unique file, so when another user makes a new one, they don't mess up any of the data from the previous user.

[image]

Is this possible, and if so how do I do this? I can upload a copy of the file, and have them download and email a copy to the admin, but that's essentially killing the whole point of using SharePoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a SharePoint document library, you can set a default file type to open when a new file is created (for example, you can set a PowerPoint file as the default file type to open). You can also customize the default file template for that library. For example, you can create a Microsoft Word template with customized headers and footers, or other custom features, and make it the default template for that library. Then, when you or your users create a new file, it opens in the appropriate program with your customized features.

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Set-a-custom-template-for-a-SharePoint-library-8e0177eb-46bd-4346-9998-330c32733c25?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE

Comment: That's almost exactly what I was looking for, now my only issue is that the file acts up when trying to work with flow. If I set it to send a verification email on file creation it just sends the empty template, not the file I finished making, and when I set it to email on file edit it doesn't send the verification email until I close and the reopen the file.

Comment: @Flotolk avoid asking further questions in the comment field, and generally multiple questions at once. The given answer is the correct way to handle this in SharePoint.