# Sharepoint file update and flow not working correctly

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, file, flow

So in a [previous question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219824/automatically-add-an-excel-file-as-one-part-of-a-list-item-in-sharepoint) I asked how to add a file to a sharepoint list. Since that is not an option, I had make them create new files every time they wanted to make a request. However, creating files on sharepoint causes some issues with Flow.

Right now my flow is set up so that When a file is modified -> Send Approval Email (With copy of file attached) -> Condition: SelectedOption equals Approved ->True: Copy file to approved requests / False: Copy file to denied requests

However, when the new file is created it reads that as a file being edited and sends the approval email with a copy of just the blank template. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition and check to see if modified != created.

Comment: So in basic mode just add the condition (Modified) (Is not equal to) (Created)? Or is there some advanced code I can use? I do want them to just have to open the file once

Comment: That still didn't do anything

Comment: Correct. For a screenshot, see step 6 in this MS blog post where they were trying to do the opposite. You'll have have not equal to instead of equal to as the condition: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Flow-Community-Blog/quot-Get-Manager-quot-For-SharePoint-Document-Library-Approvals/bc-p/38672#M20

Comment: Files and lists act very differently in flow, I have tried working with this tutorial and it did not help. The items modified and created don't even exist for files

Comment: So you added a condition so that the email would only go out if the created  is not equal to the modified, but that condition is somehow met when the file is first added and the email is sent? Can you check the flow's execution and see the values of the created/modified? Or, is this flow or another workflow/flow that is modifying the list item on create?

Comment: The issue is that there is no such condition available for excel files. There is only one flow in this folder. I can't even use the start an approval action because you can't add a link to files for that action. Even if I add a dynamic URL using the file name and the file identifier.

Comment: So modified will never equal created, it may equal null or something similar but that still makes the expression itself true.

Comment: Instead of using the "when a file is modified" trigger, use the "when an item is modified". Your library won't show up on the dropdown list, but type the name of the library in anyway. You should then have access to all list fields, including created, modified, etc., as well as file fields such as file name, path, etc.